# Install and config nvm (Node Version Manager) on MacOS Monterey

Tags: nvm, macos-monterey

I have had a lot of problems installing and configuring **Node Version Manager** on MacOS Monterrey because, although I have found a lot of information and guides to install and configure all this information, it is not easy for a Windows user like me. And I confess that I need more screenshots than text.

Do you guys have any easy solution?

Comment: Have you tried using homebrew? Install homebrew on your Mac(https://brew.sh/), then just `brew install nvm` in the terminal.

Comment: The official guide on Github: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-macos is your best bet

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that works for me, to **install and configure nvm in MacOS Monterrey**, with several steps, I will try to be clear and concise:

Exists two ways to resolve this problem:

- This way didn't work properly for me: [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) + [Gist](https://gist.github.com/nijicha/e5615548181676873118df79953cb709)

At point 3 of Gist

> Add following line to your profile. (.profile or .zshrc or .zprofile)

you can open with  `open ~/.zprofile` or `open ~/.zshrc`

- #### This way works for me: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/cooperwfloyd/51ce7748dba37d14dbabf5e942a2b4bb)

In the line

> Create a .zshrc file in Macintosh HD -> Users -> {{your user folder}}

If you don't have it, create with `touch ~/.zshrc`
Next just open to edit with `touch ~/.zshrc`

I think problem for Windows users is understand the [difference between .zprofile and .zshrc](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388622/zsh-zprofile-zshrc-zlogin-what-goes-where).

I hope that this summary will serve you, just to thank the collaborators of the articles that I have found